# Ошибка при вводе новых переменных

Tags: java

недавно начал изучать Java, буду благодарен за помощь.
Хотел написать программу для расчёта веса человека на Луне, при том что пользователь должен будет ввести свой вес на Земле, и исходя из этого высчитывался бы вес на Луне.
Почему при вводе новых переменных earth,sil у меня появляется ошибка?
Подозреваю что это делается всё по-другому, но как корректно задать вопрос в google не знаю.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Moon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите ваш вес: ");
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        double number =  scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ваш вес на Земле: " + number);

        double earth,sil;
  }

}
```

[image: Вот эта ошибка]

---

**Всем большое спасибо за ответы!**
**Извиняюсь за потраченное время**, я думал это ошибка.
Видимо я смотрел не туда куда нужно.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Код выглядит рабочим. Скорее всего вы получаете InputMismatchException, потому что вводите дробное число через точку, а не запятую

Comment: @had0uken нет у него такой проблемы; он жаловался, что у него появляются сообщения по типу "Variable "..." is never used"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы объявили две новых переменных earth,sil. IDE вам сообщает что вы их нигде не используете, возможно они были объявлены ошибочно. По факту это предупреждение(warning) а не ошибка(error).

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, стало понятно.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё правильно, проверьте или Вы Правильный класс запустили.